# FabricJs - zoom canvas to fit object

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I'm trying to set zoom to canvas in order to fit an object higher than the original canvas height. [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1akovx57/1/). If you notice, I want the canvas zoomed as it is if you uncomment these lines:

```
//canvas.zoomToPoint(new fabric.Point(10, 10), 0.75);
//canvas.renderAll();
```

I want to programmatically define the correct zoom (for this example, it's `0.75`) based on the objects on the canvas.

Comment: Unclear what you ant to achieve - you and to automatically zoom to the size that ALL present on canvas objects are fully visible or smth else?

Comment: yes, it's correct, but i often have only one object at a time on the canvas

Answer (score 8):

Resolved with :

```
canvas.zoomToPoint(new fabric.Point(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2), (canvas.height / obj.height));
    canvas.renderAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fit multiple objects use this:

```js
fabric.Canvas.prototype.zoomToFitObjects = function () {
  if (this.getObjects().length < 1) {
    return;
  }
  let x1 = Math.min(
    ...this.getObjects().map((obj) => obj.left!)
  );
  let y1 = Math.min(
    ...this.getObjects().map((obj) => obj.top!)
  );
  let x2 = Math.max(
    ...this.getObjects().map((obj) => obj.left!)
  );
  let y2 = Math.max(
    ...this.getObjects().map((obj) => obj.top!)
  );
  let height = Math.abs(y1) + Math.abs(y2);
  let width = Math.abs(x1) + Math.abs(x2);
  this.setZoom(1);
  const x = (x1 + (width / 2)) - (this.width! / 2);
  const y = (y1 + (height / 2)) - (this.height! / 2);
  this.absolutePan({ x: x, y: y});
  const heightDist = this.getHeight() - height;
  const widthDist = this.getWidth() - width;
  let groupDimension = 0;
  let canvasDimension = 0;
  if (heightDist < widthDist) {
    groupDimension = height;
    canvasDimension = this.getHeight();
  } else {
    groupDimension = width;
    canvasDimension = this.getWidth();
  }
  const zoom = (canvasDimension / groupDimension) * 0.7;
  this.zoomToPoint({ x: this.width!/2, y: this.height!/2 }, zoom);
};
```